# MongoDB storing API calls

Tags: mongodb, api, web-applications

Building a web application and need to store API calls in MongoDB. Not sure how to actually populate data from the calls into MongoDB any help/resources would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please calrify what exactly you want to store? Log that API call happened? Data sent? Some meta info? Best of all bring example of data you want to store, as trying to store, say, whole request object is hardly useful.